# Solar power charging and powering ESP32/Pi Zero W

Tags: power, solar-cell, charging

I have a Pi Zero W and ESP32 Dev kit board that I need to power outdoors. What I looking for is a solution that will use solar power during the day to power Pi and ESP32 and at the same time be able to charge Lipo battery for using during the night/cloudy days.

It should have a reasonable (3.5/4.2) battery under and over charge protections.

I have these 3 solar panels which I want to use for this but no MPPT charger controller(yet).

- 12V 10W
- 18V 20W
- 12V 10W
  (these are of course manufcturer's "exagerated" figures ;)

What options do I have with ready made solution board that does all that (and maybe more) and what can be bult using the off-the shelf components available on the marrket?

Comment: That won’t work unless you match battery = MPT voltage and estimate energy loads vs supply

Comment: ESP32 draws constant 140mA, Zero W draws 130mA at startup and after it had booted up goes down to 70mA. Would this be an estimate of energy loads?

Comment: No, but it shows load mA not mAh  and not supply average energy in mAh. You need to match Vmpt to batteries then convert down to load

Comment: I think I need to read up on the subject  any suggestions for a good start to read up?

Comment: Gr XII physics on electrical energy

Comment: Right... Just as I though...